# Nested condition subset of the top one

Tags: java

I've got this code

```
Double best = nodes.get(edge.getToNodeId());
if (best == null || (best > g+h)) {
    nodes.put(edge.getToNodeId(), g+h);
    if (best == null) {
        open.add(new State(edge.getToNodeId(), g, h, top));
    } else {
        open.modify(new State(edge.getToNodeId(), g, h, top)); 
    }    
}
```

I don't quite like it because I duplicate the `best == null` clause. Would it be better in these types of situation to duplicate the `nodes.put()` instead? Or is there some third, more readable, way without duplicates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's a matter of taste and preference. In either case, you would have to duplicate something. But, there's something that drew my attention. I don't claim it to be correct or be a solution to your problem. Hard to say without knowing the context and data structures that you use. Anyways, here we go...

I noticed that in both cases, whether `best == null` or not, you pass the same arguments, though to different methods. I suspect that this checking might occur in many other places as well. So, what if we create a method (e.g. `addOrModify()`) and move this condition statement to that method. And the method would internally decide whether to add a new `State` or modify the existing one. Somewhat similar behavior may be observed in the `java.util.Set.add(E e)` method, where the method checks if the element has already been added to the `Set` and then returns `false` without adding it twice...

Then, we end up with something like this in the client code:

```
Double best = nodes.get(edge.getToNodeId());
if (best == null || (best > g+h)) {
    nodes.put(edge.getToNodeId(), g+h);
    open.addOrModify(new State(edge.getToNodeId(), g, h, top));    
}
```

Comment: addOrModify() is an option I considered, but it would need one special argument for the "best" value. Anyway this snippet is just from an implementation of A* algorithm which is no more than 100 lines of code so I don't want to overcomplicate things. I was just wondering if the solution I've written doesn't seem ugly :)

Comment: @HonzaBrabec, well, I wouldn't say it's ugly. Maybe "a necessary evil" at most... In your case, however, I believe it's good enough.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can introduce a local variable for the result of the null check. The following expressions are also duplicated in the code:

   1. `edge.getToNodeId()`
   2. `g+h`
   3. `new State(nodeId, g, h, top)`

   I'd start with eliminating these:

   ```
   final NodeId nodeId = edge.getToNodeId();
   final Double best = nodes.get(nodeId);
   final int gPlusH = g + h; // TODO: needs a better name
   final boolean newData = best == null; // TODO: needs a better name
   if (newData || (best > gPlusH)) {
       nodes.put(nodeId, gPlusH);
       final State state = new State(nodeId, g, h, top);
       if (newData) {
           open.add(state);
       } else {
           open.modify(state);
       }
   }
   ```

   Reference: *Chapter 6. Composing Methods*, *Introduce Explaining Variable* in *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code* by Martin Fowler:

   > Put the result of the expression, or parts of the expression, 
   >   in a temporary variable with a name that explains the purpose.

   And *Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*, *G19: Use Explanatory Variables*.
2. Short variable names (like `g` and `h`) are not too readable. I suppose you have autocomplete, so using longer names does not mean more typing but it would help readers and maintainers a lot since they don't have to remember the purpose of each variable - the name would express the programmers intent.

Comment: [Sometimes short variable names are good](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/176585/633)

Comment: I know these practices you've mentioned, however I don't think there is always a need to be so dogmatic (sorry) :) g and h are the case of names @Svish mentioned. Naming variable gPlusH IMO doesn't help the maintainability in any way. It just duplicates the expression. What if I wanted to change the expression? I'd have to change the name of the variable too (not too comfortable i think). I also find edge.getToNodeId() (which translates as "get the id of the node this edge goes to") more readable than nodeId. With other things you've changed I have no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the code extract, you want to create the state if it does not exist, otherwise update it if necessary.

I would handle the special case first and continue with the normal work:

```
    final Double best = nodes.get(edge.getToNodeId());
    if (best == null) {
        best = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        open.add(new State(edge.getToNodeId(), g, h, top));
    }
    nodes.put(edge.getToNodeId(), Math.min(g + h, best));
    if (g + h < best)
        open.modify(new State(edge.getToNodeId(), g, h, top));
```

Other than that, I would think about better variable names. It could be helpful to change method signatures or objects, too. This depends on the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

What is 'g' or 'h'? How could you name your conditions in 'if' statement? Use better names and you will find the solution. I assume that 'g' is 'guru' and 'h' is 'height' :) Also you can extend your 'open' thing and inject there the operation you want. Also you can hide your conditions with a nice name or reuse these. So, you can make appropriate code changes in order to achieve the following pattern:

```
BestAndGuruAndHeightWrapper bestAndGuruAndHeightWrapper = new BestAndGuruAndHeightWrapper (nodes.get (edge.getToNodeId()), guru, height);

ConditionsCollection conditionsCollection = new ConditionsCollection ();

if (conditionsCollection.AConditionToPerform (bestAndGuruAndHeightWrapper)) {
    nodes.put(edge.getToNodeId(), bestAndGuruAndHeightWrapper.Guru + bestAndGuruAndHeightWrapper.Height);

    open.operate(new State(edge.getToNodeId(), bestAndGuruAndHeightWrapper.Guru, bestAndGuruAndHeightWrapper.Height, top), bestAndGuruAndHeightWrapper.Best);
}
```

You can also use the Decorator pattern in order to add the "if null check" responsibility to your "open object" thing.

Comment: The snippet is from an implementation of A* algorithm. In that context (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) The names 'g', 'h' are natural.